# What is a Heptagon Number™?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle, number-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with **Number** version puzzles.</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Heptagon Number™**.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Heptagon }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Numbers}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{ 12 }&\text{ 14 }\\ \hline
\text{ 31 }&\text{ 33 }\\ \hline
\text{ 47 }&\text{ 49 }\\ \hline
\text{ 88 }&\text{ 90 }\\ \hline
\text{ 234 }&\text{ 236 }\\ \hline
\text{ 597 }&\text{ 599 }\\ \hline
\text{ 815 }&\text{ 817 }\\ \hline
\text{ 901 }&\text{ 903 }\\ \hline
\text{ 1,689 }&\text{ 1,691 }\\ \hline
\text{ 6,667 }&\text{ 6,669 }\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Heptagon Numbers™,Not Heptagon Numbers™
12,14
31,33
47,49
88,90
234,236
597,599
815,817
901,903
1689,1691
6667,6669
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A Heptagon number is

> A number that when shown on a 7-segment display uses a multiple of 7 segments, thus the prefix hepta-.

For each listed number:

> 12 -> 2 + 5 = 7
>  31 -> 5 + 2 = 7
>  47 -> 4 + 3 = 7
>  88 -> 7 + 7 = 14
>  234 -> 5 + 5 + 4 = 14
>  597 -> 5 + 6 + 3 = 14
>  815 -> 7 + 2 + 5 = 14
>  901 -> 6 + 6 + 2 = 14
>  1689 -> 2 + 6 + 7 + 6 = 21
>  6667 -> 6 + 6 + 6 + 3 = 21

The numbers in the other column do not have this property.

Comment: You got it. Nice Work~!